# RestKit didReceiveData not called

Tags: ios, delegates, restkit

Im doing something like that to download a file. Everything is working correct, instead of the delegate didReceiveData which I wanna use to make a download progress bar:

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    RKRequest *downloadRequest = [RKRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    downloadRequest.delegate = self;
    downloadRequest.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
    [downloadRequest sendSynchronously];
```

After that the following delegate is called:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"TEST didLoadResponse");
}
```

But the delegate didReceiveData is never called:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSInteger)bytesReceived totalBytesReceived:(NSInteger)totalBytesReceived totalBytesExpectedToReceive:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToReceive
{
    NSLog(@"TEST didReceiveData");
}
```

Anyone an idea? I really tried a lot and I just dont find any mistake. Probably it has something to do how Im creating my `RKRequest`?

EDIT:
If I change it to that, it works:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

RKClient *client = [[RKClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL];
RKRequest *downloadRequest = [client get:@"" delegate:self];
[downloadRequest sendSynchronously];
```

Strange?

EDIT2: With the second solution I got some thread problems, so I guess the problem is that im sending and synchronous request which will lock the thread and so the didReceiveData delegates are not coming back?

Comment: not sure but perhaps didReceiveData is not a delegate method of RKRequest, but one of RKClient instead

Comment: As in the documentation, it is.

http://restkit.org/api/master/Protocols/RKRequestDelegate.html